# How is `pub(self)` visibility different from no `pub` attribute?

Tags: rust, visibility

I [see](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/visibility-and-privacy.html) that functions' visibility can be declared to be `pub(self)` within a module. How is this different from a private function with no `pub` attribute? Why does this syntax exist if they are not different?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `pub(restricted)` syntax was introduced in [RFC 1422](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1422-pub-restricted.md). It introduces two new ways to specify visibility:

- `pub(crate)`: makes the item visible to the whole current crate, but not beyond.
- `pub(in path::to::module)`: makes the item visible to the module tree specified by the path.

`pub(self)` is syntactic sugar for `pub(in self)`, which falls into the second category: `self` is just a path like `super`, `::foo`, `bar::baz` and so on. This means that, yes, `pub(self)` makes the item visible to the current module tree.

Thus, **`pub(self)` is equivalent to omitting the `pub(self)` declaration**. This is even stated [in the RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1422-pub-restricted.md#semantics):

> As noted above, the definition means that `pub(self) item` is the same as if one had written just `item`.

The RFC also mentions why this is supported:

> The main reason to support this level of generality (which is otherwise just "redundant syntax") is macros: one can write a macro that expands to `pub($arg)` item, and a macro client can pass in `self` as the `$arg` to get the effect of a non-pub definition.